# Checking the stability of a system for different values of a in R

Tags: dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, stability-theory

I have the following system:
$\dot r=r(a-r^2)$
$\dot \theta=1$
I need to check the stability of the equilibrium point (0,0) for different values of a in $R$.

MY ATTEMPT:
If $a\lt r(0)^2$, then $\dot r \lt 0$, so, stable spiral.
If $a\gt r(0)^2$, then $\dot r \gt 0$, so, unstable spiral.
If $a= r(0)^2$,, then, r=r(0), so, centre., where $r(0)=r at t=0

Is my attempt correct? Please rectify if there is any mistake and give an explanation for the correction. Thankyou.

Comment: This is very messy. Your equilibrium point is not $(0,0)$ in $(r,\theta)$. It is the origin though (e.g. $r = 0$). The stability of the origin is determined by linearizing the system. You will see that if $a < 0$ then it is stable and if $a > 0$ it is unstable. I leave the case $a = 0$ for you.

Comment: The case $a=r(0)^2$ is the same as $a>0$, there is no center here. The case $a=0$ makes the origin the unique equilibrium.

Comment: Okay, I tried using linearization. I got the eigenvalues of the jacobian matrix at (0,0) as $a\pm i$. So for a>0 and a<0 I get the unstable and stable respectively using linearization as in these cases (0,0) is hyperbolic. Am I right? But for a=0 , (0,0) is non hyperbolic ,then ,linearization can't be used. How to do in that case?

Comment: @Arastas But at a=r(0), we get a circle from ploar coordinates, then, why is it not a centre?

Comment: The circle is just another equilibrium; it exists for any $a>0$.